# Run all batch files in a folder and sub-folders

Tags: linux, batch-jobs

I am new using linux.

I have a folder with many sub-folders and sub-sub-folders.
All batch files have the same name --> R_batch_1_1.bash

Usually I use:
`sbatch  R_batch_1_1.bash` to run one by one.

Does anyone know how to execute all batch files in the folder and sub-folders at once?

Answer (score 1):

```
find /your/folder -type f -name "*.bash" -exec "{}" \;
```

Comment: I tried and I got some errors over other files, it may be something related with the directory?
mkdir: cannot create directory '/scratch': Permission denied
./b_model/R_batch_1_1.bash: line 15: cd: /scratch/miguel/: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/leave_one_set.R': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/run_dmu4.sh': No such file or directory
cp: cannot create regular file '/R.Rout': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory '/scratch': Permission denied